# How to handle sleeping mode in action script 3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I am writing an app to play some swf, however, when the swf is playing, the phone will enter the sleeping mode if I do not touch the screen.  If I set the DISABLE_KEYGUARD in Flash CS6, the phone cannot sleep when the swf finish to play.

How can the app not enter the sleeping mode when playing the swf?  Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;` to keep the device awake while running your app. You will also need to request permission to do this.... like so: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>`.

EDIT: Keep the permission. And call `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;` after the swf has finished playing if you want to allow your app to sleep again. Add it in the main app. Not the external SWF.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  When I add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/> in the .xml file, the app cannot go to sleep mode after the external swf finished to play.  I also add NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE in the external swf when it plays and NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL
 in the external swf when it stops.  However, they do not work, how can I modify the code?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I try to add change the systemIdleMode using by handleActivate  function, however, it is not always work.  How can I get the mother app's systemIdleMode by the external (child) swf?